# Change wp-signup.php Page Template

Tags: templates, page-template, user-registration, signup, wp-signup

I am using [anti-splog](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/anti-splog/) on a multisite network with the randomly changing signup URL feature. Under the hood, it is pointing to wp-signup.php file. I created an override file the plugin looks for by default and it just turns around, loads my stylesheet, and then invokes the plugin's ust-wp-signup.php original file:

```
<?php
/*
    Custom MySite Sign Up Page
*/

/**
 * Custom MySite stylesheet for signup page.
 */
function MySite_signup_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-wpsignup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/wp-signup.css', false, '1.0', 'all');
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'MySite_signup_stylesheet' );



// Invoke the default sign up page handler
require_once('plugins/anti-splog/includes/ust-wp-signup.php');
```

I need a way to make my custom wp-signup page use a page template from my theme other than the default front page theme because it does not render correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme my login is an option:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/

This should also help out:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

EDIT: 
Noticed I don't think that really answers your question (my reply above), but you should just be able to create a registration form and then POST to that random URL.  I don't know much about anti-splog at all but all you need to do is POST to the URL if it's random, but also keep in mind if using `nonce` it may be an issue as well.

Comment: It's nice to know about that plugin but I don't think it's going to work. If I was not using the changing url feature of anti-splog, it would be perfect to have it right inside a regular theme page but I need to keep the original login page. I guess I will just need to dress it up with CSS the best I can.